# A program is constantly opening and closing every 5 seconds. It's really annoying

Tags: bug-reporting

So there is this program named "@!0,27;BDH" that's constantly opening and closing in the background and i don't know how to stop it.

The problem is that, because the program opens, it's selected as the current program. Consequently, the window on which i'm working is deselected.

This is especially annoying when i'm writing text (for example : now) because i can't write more than a word before the my keystrikes aren't logged anymore.

Here's a video to illustrate : https://streamable.com/wh9y1s

Comment: What is this program? How did you install it?

Comment: i don't know what it is

Comment: Seems like your problem is NOT that you have "*XYZ that's constantly opening and closing in the background*." Your problem is that you seem to have *malware installed* that makes your system unusable. Maybe you're under attack, or maybe it's a prank, or maybe it's a mistake -- the application name does not suggest a mistake. If you don't know where it came from, then the rest of your system is suspect.  On my network, any machine with a "mystery" application of unknown origin gets wiped and reinstalled. That's what backups are for.

Comment: You can type `journalctl -xe` and hopefully it will tell you the name of the application that is starting this weird program name.

Comment: Have you rebooted yet? Are you typing that text into the terminal window? If not, unplug your keyboard and see if the problem goes away. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 1):

I started to see a similar issue after an upgrade on Ubuntu 22.04, in my case the window was named `@!2560,0;BDHF` but it seems just another instance of the same problem.

Disabling Desktop Icons Next Generation (DING) gnome-shell extension "fixed" it for me:

```
$ gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com
```

Another way to do this is by navigating to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and rename the extension directory (`ding@rastersoft.com/`) to something else (so that if something breaks, you can rename the directory again to get back to where you were).

I'm ok with no longer having desktop icons, YMMV.

For more info see:

- https://github.com/pop-os/shell/issues/1075
- https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/issues/250
- [What is @!0,27;BDH and why does it keep me stuck in activites overview mode?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1342245/1661010)

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to another session and log in at the command line to investigate, Control Alt and Function Key 1 (2,3 etc) Should take you to a new login prompt.  Control Alt F6 (might be F7) will return yo to the desktop session

Think back to what were you doing immediately before this started? That might give you somewhere to start looking.