# What is @!0,27;BDH and why does it keep me stuck in activites overview mode?

Tags: activities-overview

This bug keeps me stuck in activities overview mode showing me all running programs and folders and I can't access any of them.

I thought it was related to the browser and asked about that but we reached no answer.

I accessed from many users and found that the issue still exists.

I made some trials and found that it happens when I try to move between my running programs, folders, etc...

@!0,27;BDH: I have no idea what this is, even searching online only led me to [one post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336914/a-program-is-constantly-opening-and-closing-every-5-seconds-its-really-annoyin), you can see it in the picture. I can close all other programs but @!0,27;BDH can't be closed. Sometimes it doesn't appear but I will still be stuck at the activities overview

[image: @!0,27;BDH window]

The issue has been there since 20.10.

I updated the kernel from 5.11.0-18-generic to 5.13.0-051300rc4-generic and my version is 21.04, the bug stayed.

AMD® Iceland / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

[image: shell extensions]

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.1Gi       2.9Gi       869Mi       1.0Gi       4.1Gi
Swap:         3.7Gi          0B       3.7Gi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is @!0,27;BDH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341059/what-is-0-27bdh)

Comment: Show me `uname -r`.

Comment: @heynnema 5.11.0-18-generic

Comment: That's not the standard kernel for Ubuntu 20.10. Boot to the standard kernel and see if your problem goes away. What video card do you have? What version driver?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h`.

Comment: The left one of those running programs looks like a game. Does the problem only happen when that game is running? What if you don't start it? Or is it started automatically after each system boot?

Comment: @HuHa No, it can happen anytime: examples: while using Alt+tab or accessing overview momently. Browser, games, folders, no specific

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336914/a-program-is-constantly-opening-and-closing-every-5-seconds-its-really-annoyin : Same weird `@!0,27;BDH`

Comment: Disable `Desktop Icons Next Generation` (ding) in your gnome-shell extensions and see if the problem goes away. Remove the rc4 kernel that you installed asap.

Comment: @heynnema I do not see an answer in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @Bruni No, that was a duplicate question asked by the same user.

Comment: @SilverPlayer Have you reverted to the standard kernel yet? Have you disabled `ding` yet? Status please...

Comment: @heynnena Sorry I did not notice it was the same user.

Comment: Status please... did you disable `ding` and the rc4 kernel?

Comment: @heynnema yes, kc4 was removed, currently running 5.12.x, I disabled Ding, 1st week nothing happened but by 2nd week I face the issue once, I tried to make it happen again later but nothing faced me any more till this moment (  during 3rd week )

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Desktop Icons Next Generation (DING) gnome-shell extension may help to solve this issue:

```
$ gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com
```

Another way to do this is by navigating to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and rename the extension directory (`ding@rastersoft.com/`) to something else (so that if something breaks, you can rename the directory again to get back to where you were).

I started to see this issue after an upgrade on Ubuntu 22.04, in my case the window was named `@!2560,0;BDHF` but it seems another instance of the same problem.

For reference see:

- https://github.com/pop-os/shell/issues/1075
- https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/issues/250