# What is @!72,27;BDH and @!0,27;BDH?

Tags: bug-reporting, malware

There are other posts here asking about a mysterious program called @!0,27;BDH.
This program (is it a program?) appeared out of nowhere for me after I upgraded from 20.10 to 21.04 last Friday.
I noticed it first when attempting to share my screen on a Zoom meeting with my friends. Upon sharing a screen on Zoom, you may choose to share your entire desktop screen or a specific application. This `@!0,27;BDH` program appeared as one of the options for screen sharing. I could also see it if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.[image: ctrl+alt+tab showing @!0,27;BDH]

I saw the other posts about `@!0,27;BDH` and none of them presented any solutions or answers. And this program didn't affect me in the exact same way as it did other people. It appears that it gets people stuck in Activities Overview Mode like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342245/what-is-0-27bdh-and-why-does-it-keep-me-stuck-in-activites-overview-mode). It happened to me a few times but not too often and it has never been like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336914/a-program-is-constantly-opening-and-closing-every-5-seconds-its-really-annoyin).

I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 21.04 from scratch today, erasing the disk and all. I had, of course, backup all my files. Upon finishing the installation I noticed that it now appears as `@!72,27;BDH` and not `@!0,27;BDH`. [image: ctrl+alt+tab showing @!72,27;BDH]

I never noticed it before when I was using 20.10. I'm starting to feel really worried about this. Does anyone have any idea what it is and how to get rid of it?

Here it is as an option for screen sharing on Zoom.[image]

EDIT: showing `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` as requested:

```
    jorgepotyguara@jorgepotyguara-Inspiron-3268:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
    ls: cannot access '/home/jorgepotyguara/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

    jorgepotyguara@jorgepotyguara-Inspiron-3268:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
    total 20
    drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 abr 20 07:44 .
    drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 abr 20 07:49 ..
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jun 10 20:06 ding@rastersoft.com
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 abr 20 07:44 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 abr 20 07:44 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Just my 2c. I think it has to do with windowtitles under wayland (which is why it seems to affect only users of wayland under 21.04. This is the only search I found which does not involve confused Ubuntu users: https://github.com/amivaleo/Show-Desktop-Button/issues/10 . Unfortunately it surpasses my skillset.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Do you have any themes installed/selected?

Comment: Done that @heynnema! I do not have any themes installed.
@Bruni, I am using Xorg as I was having trouble screen sharing on Zoom on Wayland.

Comment: Disable `Desktop Icons NG` (ding), restart gnome-shell, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you, @heynnema! It appears to have worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, or use the `Extensions` or `Tweaks` app...

Disable `Desktop Icons NG` (ding) and restart gnome-shell (if on X11), or log out/in (if in Wayland). Remove/uninstall ding.

Reinstall the original `Desktop Icons` gnome-shell extension...

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`

Restart gnome-shell (if on X11), or log out/in (if on Wayland).

Report this issue at https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/issues